# Display long text in multiple UITextView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextview

I need to display articles with pictures or videos maybe later. I need to display this in multiple pages. User and swipe up and down to change page. The pages need to slide out and in. What are the good ways to do this? I did some research and have some thoughts with questions.

1. UITextview. Using one layout manager for each UITextview, it can decide how to separate the article into different pages. Then I need to put UITextview to different views. Add all the views to controller and slide in and out. Question with this approach: how do I know how many views do I need?
2. UIScrollView. How can it slide in and out?

Thanks,
Lee

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer `UIScrollView` with Paging.

Here are a few examples

[Example 1](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-virtual-pages-in-uiscrollview.html)

[Example 2](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/)

Comment: Thanks for replying. These two examples doesn't seem to show how to decide how many pages you'll need initially. For example, example 2 used 3 pages directly. But my question is how to know you need 3 pages... If I know, I can also use UITextview to create slide up and down effect.

Comment: The way to identify 'how many pages you'll need initially' is, calculate the number of pages using the frame inner controls. ex: if you require to display two images per each page and you have total of 6 images, the total number of pages you'll need initially is  6/2 = 3pages.

Comment: But it's not that simple. It's rich text. Maybe I need insert image in the middle. Suppose I have 1000 words, 3 images need to insert into them, a title, a author need to display. They have different font. Then how do I know how many pages I need?